# Select attributes from different joined tables with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Can't get myself to do something as easy as good ol'

```
SELECT phrase.content, meaning.content
FROM phrase JOIN meaning
ON phrase.id = meaning.phrase_id
```

All the examples I can find in the documentation/SO are variations of

```
a = Phrase.query.join(Meaning).all()
```

which doesn't really work cause then `a` is a list of `Phrase` objects, whereas I want to select one attribute from `Phrase` and one from `Meaning`.

Anybody? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q = db.session.query(Phrase.content, Meaning.content).join(Meaning).all()
```

Comment: How can I do the same in flask-sqlalchemy, since this one returns Query object, but I need flask's BaseQuery object which has .paginate for example. Si as @laurids asked, how to do it with Phrase.query.join, not with db.session.query?